# Can not operate the option "Run on Hadoop" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I installed Hadoop-0.20.2(single node) and  configured it on Linux(Centos).I installed Eclipse and added Eclipse-plugin for Hadoop. I put dataset in /home/Hadoop/input/ali.txt . I am not able to run Wordcount example on Hadoop in Eclipse. When I select the option "to Run on Hadoop", Something doesn't happen. 
In addition , when running  Wordcount example in Eclipse as java application, encounter with the following error:

```
Input path does not exist: file:/home/hadoop/workspace/wordcount/home/hadoop/input/ali.txt
```

help me.

Answer (score 0):

Without the details about which is your $HADOOP_HOME directory and how you configured eclipse before trying to run the program, it is difficult to pin-point the error. However, this is a nice step-by-step guide on [creating and testing a Hadoop project using eclipse.](http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/23%20-%20create%20the%20project.html)

Comment: thanks, $HADOOP_HOME=/home/Hadoop/opt/  and I configured eclipse based on following link: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwiLzrOk-JLHAhXEiSwKHVl-DCE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tecmint.com%2Finstall-eclipse-classic-in-rhel-centos-fedora%2F&ei=RYfCVcuXAcSTsgHZ_LGIAg&usg=AFQjCNHMD6d9s3Je9cxdBlOaQUpl0Qw2_w&bvm=bv.99261572,d.bGg